# CSS not being loaded from CDN (CloudFiles)

Tags: 7, cdn

I've got CDN installed and configured and I've copied all of my css up to the CDN.

The CSS urls change from this (using my hosts IP address):

```
@import url("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/modules/system/system.base.css?mhdfaw");
```

When I enable the CDN module, they look like this:

```
@import url("http://b24fb3007bd5cf6f616a-a6cd251ed0dfba89acb0fcd5fb378f4a.r38.cf1.rackcdn.com/modules/system/system.base.css?mhdfaw");
```

When I copy that url and paste it into my browser, the file exists and is being served by the CDN just fine. I have tested EVERY css file in the source and every single one of them exists, but my page is completely unstyled. None of the CSS files are being applied at all.

I'm not referring to the images in the stylesheets, I'm referring to ALL of the styles.

What the heck?

EDIT: Here is a link to my site, in case that helps:

```
http://108.166.112.120/blog
```

Comment: Did you watch the transfer with Live HTTP Headers, or the network tab in FF/Chrome?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Chrome. I opened the Inspector Network tab and watched the files load. I can see each of the css files is being loaded. The Headers tab shows the response code is a 304 Not Modified and the Response tab shows the full CSS file. But the rules are not applied to the page.

Comment: I've tried several browsers and none of them render the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files had the wrong mime-type.

I wrote a php script using Rackspace's Cloud Files PHP api to upload all of my files to the Cloud Files container. All of the files had the default mime type/content type of "text/plain". I changed the content types of the css files to "text/css" and it all started working.